# ui-router nested views do not reload parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I have nested view with own controller. How can I load nested view without reloading parent controller?

```
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("aaa", {
                views: {
                    'aaa': {
                        templateUrl: "/aaa.html",
                        controller: "aaaController"
                    }
                },
                params: {
                    id: null
                },
            }).state("aaa.bbb", {
                views: {
                    'bbb': {
                        templateUrl: "/bbb.html",
                        controller: "bbbController"
                    }
                },
                params: {
                    id: null
                }
            });
//link
    <a ui-sref="aaa.bbb({id: row.getProperty(\'Id\')})"></a>
```

Every time I call bbb view aaaController gets loaded.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid this behaviour. Having a nested state means that there have been other states accessed by the user before getting to the nested state. If there are Controllers that manage the views of the parent states, it only makes sense to execute the said controllers so the views can be populated.